# PHP To Select From MySQL & Insert Into Drop Down List

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have searched the internet and I just cant seem to get my head around what to do in order to populate my drop down list from my database.

I have a table called users where there are roles such as chairman, secretary and admin.

My code is as follows:

```
<td>
   <span id="spryselect1">
      <select name="chairperson" id="chairperson">
      </select>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">You Must Choose A Chairperson For This Meeting</span>   
   </span>
</td>
```

How do I populate a drop down list so that it shows all the chairman available?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. You probably need to work on the wrapper function that creates the drop-down but it's a start. If you are not comfortable with `mysql_fetch_object()` and you are more familiar with arrays then you can user `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
    <?php
        mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
        mysql_select_db("mydb");
        $result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");

        function sql_to_select ($result) {
            $output = '<select name="chairperson" id="chairperson">'
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                $output. = '<option value="' . $row->role_id . '">' . $row->role . '</option>';
            $output .= '</select>'; 
            return $output
        }
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>
        <h3>Here will come the select</h3>
        <div class="wrap-select">
            <?php print sql_to_select($result); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a very basic level, you need to loop through each result and output an '...' element to the list:

```
<select name="chairperson" id="chairperson">
<?php
// ... Assumes you already connected to and selected a database
$result = mysql_query('SELECT ...');
foreach (mysql_fetch_assoc($result) as $row) :
  ?>
  <option value="<?= $row->id_column; ?>"><?= $row->column_to_display; ?></option>
  <?php
endforeach;
?>
</select>
```

Obviously, you'll need to replace "id_column" with your primary key or whatever you want to use to uniquely identify the list item, and "column_to_display" should be "name" or "title" or whatever should be displayed in the option.

Comment: hi thanks for that, unfortunately it is not picking up the values from the database. my sql statement looks like this > $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE role = chairperson');

Comment: You'll need to put quotes around "chairperson"